# How to Stripe Process payment using the WooCommerce REST API?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, woocommerce-rest-api

How can we Process the payment of Stripe Payment Gateway?

I am using the WooCommerce REST API for Developing mobile Apps Here My Question is how to pay using the REST API?

Can I use the Stripe Payment gateway in Mobile Application Developing?

Answer (score 1):

For Payment using WooCommerce Rest API via stripe payment gateway, it is very easy to make the custom endpoint and call the public functions as website works.

**Below are the steps to Do payment of stripe in woocommerce REST API.**

1) You need to Integrate the Stripe SDK for your mobile application.

- For the iOS SDK Integration follow  [Documentation](https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/index.html)
- For the Android SDK Integration follow  [Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android)

2) After the SDK integration in the mobile apps you have to get the publishable key from the server( from your woocommerce admin panel checkout settings and choose stripe ).

- If you don't have the stripe account details for the transaction don't worry you can create the stripe account over  [Here](https://dashboard.stripe.com/register)
- you can get the available payment method and account details of the stripe as well using this code...  [Click Here](https://gist.github.com/Mr-AjayM/0de340c3f9a47f7481a470ac82e4927d)

3)  Now you have a publishable key for the generate the payment token from the SDK So, now we create the API for the Payment.

- Create the custom endpoint same as the get payment method API.
- Using this [master code](https://gist.github.com/Mr-AjayM/172a6962567b0228889daed4a6b88fcb) you can generate the payment method API in WooCommerce.

**Have a fun and Do Payment via WooCommerce REST API for Stripe**